# What filesystem use to backup Ubuntu and Windows on an external drive?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, backup

i might ask a silly question but i don't want to make this process twice.

Currently, i have Windows 10 in an internal drive(1T), Ubuntu on an external drive(1T) and another external drive (500 gb) which i would like to use to make backups of both systems.

My question is: Should i make two partitions, one with ext4 and other with ntfs?

Thanks for all your comments and answers!

PD: would you recommend me a program to backup files in Ubuntu?

Comment: Both will read and write to NTFS by default.

Comment: @Terrance i just format the whole disk as ntfs? Beacuse is not formatted.

Comment: That would be fine.  I backup from my Ubuntu and my Windows to a shared 3TB drive formatted as NTFS.   I actually think that in my system all my drives are formatted to NTFS except for my drive I boot to Ubuntu with, which is formatted to ext4.  Windows by default will not read ext4, that is why I went with NTFS.

Comment: You're welcome!  Oh, I just backup my stuff with scripts that I wrote in bash myself, but you could look into [deja-dup](https://www.linux.com/learn/total-system-backup-and-recall-deja-dup) as a backup application.

Comment: note: with NTFS (nt fs has modified, archive, ro, system only attrs only I think); it doesn't store all POSIX (GNU/Linux) file attributes & permissions (viewable with `stat` or `ls -ltrha` etc) so `cp` files there via script will result in some of this info getting lost though a backup|tarball|.. (prior to `cp`) can be used to prevent this loss.  if you only care about the data (data within the file) it's ok as only metadata is lost.   yes certain windows versions will use *nix formats where this won't be lost but ntfs is by far the easiest.